# Ĉu iu havas informon pri la muzikgrupo La Verda Stel’?

Tags: culture

Mi trovis ligilon al ĉi tiu filmeto en Mastodon. Mi multe scivolas pri la grupo. De kiu jaro ĝi estas? Ĉu ili havas aliajn kantojn? Ĉu iu scias ion pri ili? La priskribo de la filmeto diras nur ke ri trovis ĝin en brokanta vendejo sen scii ke ĝi estas en Esperanto.

https://tubaro.aperu.net/v/ytb_4cXlTumFRyU

Comment: Alia kanto: https://tubaro.aperu.net/v/ytb_qpFNpmcWFHM/

Comment: Estas interesa blogartikolo pri la temo kun diskuto pri teorioj en la komentejo. https://kajtielplu.home.blog/2019/05/21/trovendaj-vivaj-au-malvivaj/